# What is known about global well ordering of classes in Gödel-Bernays?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I would like to have something like a linear order on classes, such that every instantiated predicate of classes has a minimal instance in that order.  For my purposes, it is fine to assume V=L for sets.

Comment: I'm not quite clear as to what you mean. If you assume $V=L$ then you have a definable well-ordering of the sets, therefore every non-empty class must have a least element.

Comment: @AsafKaragila  I want well ordering not *in* classes, but *of* classes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the context of models of second-order arithmetic, Mostowski showed that starting with the theory $Z_2$ (the second-order arithmetic analogue of Kelley-Morse) together with the scheme of dependent choices, one can use forcing to add a well-ordering relation on classes so that the full second-order comprehension scheme continues to hold in the language with the new relation. The argument appeared in his paper "[Models of second order arithmetic with definable Skolem functions](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm75/fm75125.pdf)" [Fund. Math. 75 (1972), 223–234] and was later corrected in "[Erratum to the paper `Models of second order arithmetic with definable Skolem functions'](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm84/fm84127.pdf)" [Fund. Math. 84 (1974), 173]. Initially, Mostowski used only the choice scheme to prove the result.

Mostowski's argument generalizes to the theory Kelley-Morse together with the scheme of dependent choices. The *scheme of dependent choices states* that if a second-order definable relation has no terminal nodes, then it has an $\omega$-chain. The forcing is supposed to be akin to the forcing argument that a global well-ordering class can be added to a model of ZFC, but in this case the condition are classes, and so we have a hyperclass forcing (in Sy Friedman's terminology). I only know about this construction from conversations with Ali Enayat, who will probably give many more details when he is around.

Comment: Terrific.  I will take some time to absorb this.  Since I really want this in a weak fragment of ZFC, the use of $Z_2$ is very encouraging.

Comment: @ColinMcLarty I think the key to making the argument work is having full second-order comprehension (which GB doesn't have) plus the dependent choice scheme for classes. This is, I think, what is needed for hyperclass forcing to preserve comprehension in the extended language. But I am hoping Ali will be here to say more.

Comment: A beautiful result.  I fear it sinks my strategy for the problem that led to this question, but maybe that failure points the way to what will work.